# Issue with imagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I've got a little tiny problem when i present a ImagePickerController..

Here is my code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
```

And this is what i see on my device:

[image]

We can see something which can be a navigationBar but i set it to HIDDEN and nothing change..

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What's the frame property of your current view controller? Perhaps this is somehow incorrect and the image picker is using it to be sized? What's the output of `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));` ?

Comment: can you post more code? it appears your error may be somewhere in your implementation.

Comment: You hide the status bar right? The navigation bar isn't a part of the UIImagePickerController because it is modal and not included in a UINavigationController so it must be your underlying view controller.